# Highcharts range selector date formats from C#

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, highcharts

I have a C# util function that returns the DateTimeFormat for different regions. How can I use this to set the range selector date formats for High charts for inputDateFormat and inputEditDateFormat. Is there an easy way to convert between these formats?

My C# dateformats looks like this : MM-dd-yyyy

which I need to map to the high chart format %m-%d-%Y

Comment: Hi @Manoj Sreekumar, So you need to only convert the string 'MM-dd-yyyy' to '%m-%d-%Y' ?

Answer (score 1):

Well, you aren't clear about what you want. But I guess, you have different C# date formats for different regions. And you want to map all of them to HighCharts date format.

So the trick to always keep your data as DateTime type in C#, so you can have 1 DateTime value for all different formats. Then serialize/deserialize to Date type in JS. This way we decouple the C# format to JS format. And for HighCharts, when you getting/setting date value, just use JS Date object.

```js
let dateDeserilizedFromBackEnd = new Date(2020, 02, 27);
let dateAsStringForHighCharts = moment(dateDeserilizedFromBackEnd).format('MM-DD-YYYY');
alert(dateAsStringForHighCharts);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: The highcharts  inputDateFormat and inputEditDateFormat requires a date format string. Not a date value. I guess my question was if there is a standard way to serialize/deserialize between the date format strings

Comment: If that's the case, you can use some formatter lib such as https://momentjs.com/ with ease.

Comment: I could not find an example in moment js to convert date format strings. Can you provide an example momentjs function that can do this if you know?